# Is there any other matrix that has the property of having his $n$ eigenvalues equal to zero and $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that if $A$ is a zero matriz of order $n$ it has all of his eigenvalues equal to zero, but, at the same time, you can find $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Is there any other matrix that has this property? Or the zero matrix is the only one?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you see this property "if A is a zero matriz of order n it has all of his eigenvalues equal to zero, but, at the same time, you can find n linearly independent eigenvectors"?

Comment: Hint: What could you conclude about your matrix if you write it in the coordinate system determined by those linearly independent eigenvectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no: the zero-matrix is the only matrix with this property.

In general, an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ that has a set of $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors (accounting for all eigenvalues), then it is **diagonalizable**. That is, we can write $A = PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $A$, and $P$ is a matrix whose columns are a corresponding (linearly independent) set of eigenvectors.

If $A$ has $0$ as its only eigenvalue, it follows that $D = 0$. Thus, whatever $P$ we choose, we have
$$
A = PDP^{-1} = P0P^{-1} = 0.
$$
So, $A$ must be the zero-matrix.

More generally, a similar argument shows that if $A$ has only one eigenvalue $\lambda$ and a set of $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, then $A$ must be the corresponding multiple of the identity matrix, $A = \lambda I$.